# How to reflect carriage returns properly in PowerShell output stream?

Tags: python, powershell, logging, conda

I might have a very specific situation here but hope someone can give some insight...

I am using a powershell script to install and manage conda environments for python 3. When calling conda commands we want to output *everything* from those commands both to the console and to a log file.

The current strategy is this:

```
$logFile = C:/some/log.path    
$thisScript = {. ./conda command}
. $thisScript *>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath $logFile
```

This works well except for one thing:
The conda commands usually output a progress bar of sorts (not to a progress stream, since these were written for cmd.exe) and in the console normally these bars fill up to 100% on a single line, probably through the use of CR characters, I'm guessing?) But outputting this way  spits out every single time these progress bars refresh as a new line, like so:

```
some-package        |            | 0% 
some-package        | #####      | 50% 
some-package        | ########## | 100%
```

We have a lot of these packages so these repeat entries make the log file tedious.
Anyone have any ideas on how to allow the output stream to treat carraige return characters appropriately and overwrite lines, both in the console and in the log file?

Comment: That kind of output is not designed for redirection (for the reason you state). It would be better to tell the program that's generating that kind of output not to do that.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Is correct. If that's not an option, you could try filtering it out like `where { $_ -notlike '*%' }`

Comment: I believe `conda -q` or `conda --quiet` will not output progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Suppress the progress bar](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Output,%20Prompt,%20and%20Flow%20Control%20Options) with `-q/--quiet`. The link is for `conda install` but this is a common parameter.

---

If your goal is to see the progress bar but not have it output to many lines in the log file unfortunately there is not a way to achieve this I am aware of, short of running the process asynchronously and processing the output as it is received in the way you want (e.g. output everything to console, write only 100% progress bars to the log file, but this would be 100% a custom solution).